# how to remove characters '\U0000fffc' from nsstring ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am developing chat application. In iOS 8, i am sending text and image, while sending image with text a characters "\U0000fffc" are prefixed to nsstring.

I tried using the below code,but it is not working

```
NSCharacterSet *characterset=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\U0000fffc"];
NSString *newString = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterset];
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If those are literally the characters occurring in the string, you could try `[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U0000fffc" withString:@""]`. Creating a character set with a string breaks apart the string into its constituent characters before doing the comparison, so it doesn't have the effect you want.

Comment: I tried but still not working..

Comment: No, work out why they are there, not how to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to All who have answered and contributed. I fixed using below code

```
NSString *codeString = @"\uFFFC";
NSString *msg=[msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:codeString withString:@""];
```

If I used above code then compiled errors are fixed and worked....!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"This is my string \U0000fffc";
NSString *strModified = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\U0000fffc" withString:@""]; 
NSLog(@"%@",strModified);
```

Try this. Hope will work for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have faced the same situation and after digging in some more I have found that the said character is in fact `NSAttachmentCharacter` which the function `-(void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;` adds to your attributed string to mark the position of a `NSTextAttachment` in your string and you shouldn't replace it anyways.
If you are still facing trouble working with your Strings, provide more information about the problem, otherwise, stick to your current implementation.

Answer (score -1):

> This is the replacement character � (often a black diamond with a white question mark or an empty square box) is a symbol found in the Unicode standard at codepoint U+FFFD in the Specials table. It is used to indicate problems when a system is unable to render a stream of data to a correct symbol. It is usually seen when the data is invalid and does not match any character.

This can be removed as follow

```
NSString *codeString = @"\\ufffc";  
NSString *newString=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:codeString withString:@""];
```

P.S : "**/uFFFC**" didn't worked for me.

Comment: How did you tried, with double slash or single slash?

Comment: Try '\' not '/'.